# datagrid cellvaluechanged event handler for dynamic object

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am programmatically creating a datagrid and I want to take the value of a cell which has been changed from the user, in order to add it to another datagrid.

My code is this:

```
connTo.Open();

SqlDataReader sqlFromReader1 = null;
SqlDataReader sqlFromReader2 = null;
SqlDataReader sqlFromReader3 = null;

SqlCommand myFromCommand1 = new SqlCommand("select distinct m.catid1, c.descr "+
"from material m "+
"inner join cat1 c on c.id = m.catid1", connTo);
sqlFromReader1 = myFromCommand1.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Load(sqlFromReader1);

for (i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //int c1 = (int)(dt1.Rows[i]["catid1"]);
    TabPage tbg = new TabPage(dt1.Rows[i]["descr"].ToString());
    tabControl1.Controls.Add(tbg);

    TabControl tbi = new TabControl();
    tbi.Name = i.ToString() + i.ToString();

    SqlCommand myFromCommand2 = new SqlCommand(
        "select distinct m.catid2, c.descr " +
        "from material m " +
        "inner join cat2 c on c.id = m.catid2 "+
        "and m.catid1 = " + dt1.Rows[i]["catid1"].ToString(), connTo);
        sqlFromReader2 = myFromCommand2.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Load(sqlFromReader2);

    for (int k = 0; k < dt2.Rows.Count; k++)
    {
        //int c2 = (int)(dt2.Rows[k]["catid2"]);
        TabPage tbgi = new TabPage(dt2.Rows[k]["descr"].ToString());
        tbi.Controls.Add(tbgi);
        tbi.Left = 1;
        tbi.Top = 1;
        tbi.Width = 880;
        tbi.Height = 400;


        DataGridView gv = new DataGridView();

        gv.Width = 850;
        gv.Height = 340;            
        gv.Left = 10;
        gv.Top = 10;
        gv.ColumnCount = 4;
        gv.Columns[0].Name = "code";
        gv.Columns[0].Width = 120;
        gv.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;

        gv.Columns[1].Name = "name";
        gv.Columns[1].Width = 450;
        gv.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;

        gv.Columns[2].Name = "price";
        gv.Columns[2].Width = 80;
        gv.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;

        gv.Columns[3].Name = "qty";
        gv.Columns[3].Width = 120;

        SqlCommand myFromCommand3 = new SqlCommand(
            "select m.code, m.descr, m.cost1 price " +
            "from material m " +
            "where m.catid1 = " + dt1.Rows[i]["catid1"].ToString() + " " +
            "and m.catid2 = " + dt2.Rows[k]["catid2"].ToString(), connTo);

        sqlFromReader3 = myFromCommand3.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        dt3.Load(sqlFromReader3);

        for (int l = 0; l < dt3.Rows.Count; l++)
        {
            gv.Rows.Add(dt3.Rows[l]["code"].ToString(), dt3.Rows[l]["descr"].ToString(), dt3.Rows[l]["price"].ToString(), "");
        }

        tbgi.Controls.Add(gv);                       
    }
    tbg.Controls.Add(tbi);
```

Now I want to catch when the user changes the value of gv.Columns[3].Name ("qty") to add this value and the rest of the row data to a new datalist.

How can this been done? Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood your problem since the event you mention in the title of the question is exactly what I believe will help you. I'll answer but if this doesn't help please try and explain the problem further. Also, you can use dt3 as the datasource for your datagridview rather than creating the rows as you do right now.

Answer (score 0):

The `CellValueChanged` event should work in this case.

When you create each new `DataGridView` instance and add it to a tab just add an event handler:

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
```

Then you have the method `dataGridView1_CellValueChanged` in single place which is used by all the event handlers.

The signature of the `CellValueChanged` event handler takes `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` which has a property for both the column and row index that changed. So you have code like this:

```
void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        // Now you can cast sender to a DataGridView and copy the row at e.RowIndex
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv == null)
            return;

        // Here you get the cell value
        var cellValue = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend assigning dt3 as a datasource. If you do use a datasource rather than an unbound grid the copying of the row will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: ok, but how can i have the values of the Column so i can copy them?